# Will it be fun to go to Legoland with my family?

Tags: legoland

I am 31 years old . My elder sister and mother are going to visit me. I want to see whether it is suitable to bring them to LegoLand.

Comment: Are you an AFOL? Are they, or something similar?

Comment: Please read the meta topic: [Should questions about LEGO events, themeparks and other things unrelated to building be allowed?](http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/q/203/132)

Comment: Apparently, there's a possibility that you'll [be turned away if you don't have any children with you](http://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/legoland-dream-dies-for-man-63-over-rule-that-adults-must-be-accompanied-by-kids-1.1358249) - check with the park you wish to visit before buying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My wife and sister-in-law enjoyed our trip to LEGOLand with our sons, everyone enjoyed the models, however not everyone was as keen on the rides, you mileage without kids to share the rides with may be different.

The question then comes down to whether you feel the model world is going to justify the entrance fee, personally I found the UK park to be (comparatively) expensive compared to other theme parks in England.

Comment: I had a similar experience.  My wife and I had a great time at Legoland (I've been to the one in Billund and Florida).  However, my wife wasn't as interested in examining the models as I was.